# VALUE error SUMIFS with TRIM - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, valueerror, sumifs

I'm trying to sum cost by 4 criteria (date + 3 ID numbers).

Somehow the formula doesn't catch all relating cells. So I end up with less cost then is actually there according to those 4 criteria.

So I thought I'd try and TRIM all the arguments, to make sure there's no issues with spaces etc. Now I get a #VALUE error though
-> "Array Arguments to SUMIFS are of different size"

This is the formula I'm using:

=SUMIFS('Raw Data Tik Tok'!H:H;TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$A:$A);TRIM($A2);TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$C:$C);TRIM($D2);TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$E:$E);TRIM($F2);TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$G:$G);TRIM(H2))

Here's sample of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UvxwQEyWNcXsyqX5wp6-VjSvXG2lXEKQmVSk9dVqbVg/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS('Raw Data Tik Tok'!E:E;
 TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$A:$A); TRIM($A2);
 TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$B:$B); TRIM($B2);
 TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$C:$C); TRIM($C2);
 TRIM('Raw Data Tik Tok'!$D:$D); TRIM(D2)))
```